# How can access invisible custom UITableViewCell in iOS sdk?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I have `UITableView` with custom `UITableviewCell`.Each custom cell contains `UITextField`.I am using following code for accessing custom tableView cell

```
CustomCell *nextCell = (CustomCell*)[self.mTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath];
```

This code is fine for VISIBLE custom cell and i can see the value in console like this...

```
CustomCell: 0x10642aa0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 278.435; 320 40); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x10642c40>”
```

But for INVISIBLE cell,console value like this “null”? Why its happen?Please help me.I am using ios7 with xcode 5.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.textfiled1.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
        cell.textfiled1.delegate = self;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with invisible cell, cell that aren't displayed at all or just hidden ? Could you provide your cellForRowAtIndexPath method ?

Comment: Probably because the cell you are trying to access isn't visible ? and as such isn't created.

Comment: @Justafinger,INVISIBLE Cell meant that UITablleView scroll up and down, some cell move from visible to invisible area..

Comment: @Justafinger,appended my cellForRowAtIndexpath method.

Answer (score 0):

Cells are never "invisible". When a cell is moved off the screen (because of scrolling) it doesn't stay off the screen it is reused by the table view for the cell that has just come onto the screen.

i.e. you might have a table view with 100 items but it will only ever create about 10 cells.

For this (and many, many other reasons) you shouldn't be storing data in the cell (or any view).

If you have a text field in a cell and you want to remember what the text was then when the text field is edited (using the delegate methods) you should store the text into a property so that it can be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Your tableview is capable of having reference of Visible cells only. You cannot relay on the dynamic contents of the table view.

If you want data to be retained store them in array when the cell is becoming invisible.